# Why setting labels.text from NSMutableArray does not work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json

The following code

```
NSMutableArray *textLabels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:cell.textLabel1.text, cell.textLabel2.text, cell.textLabel3.text, cell.textLabel4.text, cell.textLabel5.text, nil];
                    for (int i=0; i<json.count; ++i)
 {
   textLabels[i] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%@",[json[i] valueForKey:@"text"]]];
 }
```

write to textLabels array correct string values, but labels on the simulator do not change. Why?

Comment: json is " NSArray * ", I get it from the backend.

Comment: @luk2302 It is not equal if i'll write cell.textLabel1.text = @"something"; ?

Comment: Where's the code that actually attempts to update the text of the labels? The code you posted only populates an array of strings.

Comment: you should save the labels in the array rather than the texts

Comment: No, it is not, since you do not write to the text property.

Comment: @rmaddy BTW - it is HAPaperViewController, complex structure (like tableView in tableView)

Comment: @luk2302 how can I update labels.text values in the cycle?

Comment: Your code cannot work. You're updating `String` objects rather than text properties of `UILabel`s. A solution is to assign tags to the labels, then get the label by tag in the loop and update the value. PS: And don't use `valueForKey`, it's `objectForKey` or key subscripting.

Comment: @vadian You mean I need to create a dictionary with "Label - tag" structure?

Comment: No, assign a tag to each `UILabel` instance either in Interface Builder or – if the labels are created programmatically – in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in order of the JSON array. Then get the label with `(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:i];` and update the text property. Any additional collection object is not required.

Comment: @vadian Yes, but how can I invoke text property of `(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:i]`? Because viewWithTag is a label (`UILable `') type

Comment: `UILabel *textLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:i];` `textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat...`

Comment: @vadian So yes, exactly! But it is necessary to understand that all views in Obj-c have tag = 0. So it's better to start tagging labels from 1. (It's for other users)

Comment: Start wherever you want and add the offset `(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:i + offset]`. `offset` = value of first tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you think asking the label for its text returns an updatable reference to the label value, but this is not the case. The returned string is an immutable object and your code is simply replacing those values with other immutable values.

To update the labels you should hold references to the labels themselves in an array, then you can index into that array and set the text of each. You don't need to store any of the text in an array.

You can add the labels to an array manually or with an `IBOutletCollection` depending on what your UI definition is.